# How to monitor queue health in celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have the following set-up:

- Generic worker pool with 100 workers
- High priority worker pool with 50 workers
- I used such large numbers because most of the time my tasks spend waiting for I/O with very long timeouts (doing HTTP requests that can take up to 20s to respond)
- Using RabbitMQ as the broker
- I have set up celeryd as a deamon using the init.d [scripts](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/generic-init.d) from celery'd github, with the following parameters:
  `CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=600 -c:low_p 100 -c:high_p 50 -Q:low_p low_priority_queue_name -Q:high_p high_priority_queue_name"`

My problem is, sometimes the queue seems to "back up"...  that is it will stop consuming tasks. It seems there are to scenarios for this:

- There is a slow build-up of "unacknowledged" messages in the broker, even though `celery inspect active` will show that not all workers are used up - that is, I will only see a few active tasks
- The queue will just stop consuming new tasks, without the buildup.
- When in its "dead" state, using `strace` on the worker processes returns nothing... completely zero activity from the worker

I would appreciate any information or pointers on:

- How I can debug it. I can use `strace` to see what the worker processes are doing, but so far that has been useful in telling me that the worker is hanging
- How I can monitor this, and possible do auto-recovery. There are many tools for managing celery (`flower` and `events` but they are both excellent in real-time - but don't have any automated monitoring/alarming functionality). Am I just better off writing my own monitoring tools with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)?

Also, I am starting my tasks from django-celery

Comment: Did you solve this problem eventually?

Comment: This is old, but two causes of backed up queues that I know of are: (1) you're creating tasks within tasks. If you do that, you'll eventually get to the point where you don't have a worker to consume the task within a task, and you'll freeze. (2) If you're using requests, to make lots of downloads or whatever, it doesn't have a default timeout, so it can totally freeze if you have a download error. Once a worker freezes, it's done.

Answer (score 4):

A very basic queue watchdog can be implemented with just a single script that’s run every minute by cron. First, it fires off a task that, when executed (in a worker), touches a predefined file, for example:

```
with open('/var/run/celery-heartbeat', 'w'):
    pass
```

Then the script checks the modification timestamp on that file and, if it’s more than a minute (or 2 minutes, or whatever) away, sends an alarm and/or restarts the workers and/or the broker.

It gets a bit trickier if you have multiple machines, but the same idea applies.

Answer (score 3):

@goro,if you are making requests to foreign services, you should try [gevent or eventlet](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=gevent#celeryd-pool) pool implementation instead of spawning 100500 workers. I also had problem, when celery workers stops consuming tasks, it was caused by a bug with [**celery+gevent+sentry(raven)**](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1341) combination.

One thing I figure out about Celery, is that it could work fine without any monitoring if all done right(*currently I'm doing >50M tasks per day*), but if it's not, monitoring will not help you very much. "Disaster recovery" in Celery is a bit tricky, not all things will work as you expect :(

You should break you solution on smaller peaces, may be separate some tasks between different queues. At some point, you'll find code snippet which cause problems.

Comment: Do you have a link to a bug report or some other information on this "bug with celery+gevent+sentry(raven) combination"?

Comment: I am also interested in hearing more about this celery+gevent+sentry(raven) bug

Answer (score 3):

I would think this is because of workers prefetching tasks. If this is still a problem you can update celery to 3.1 and use `-Ofair` worker option. The config option that I tried using before `-Ofair` was `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER`. However, setting `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1` (its lowest value) does not help since workers will still prefetch one task in advance.

See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#prefork-pool-improvements
and especially http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#caveats.